# How to convert IplImage(OpenCV) to ALLEGRO_BITMAP (A5) fast?

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage, allegro5

Is there a fastest way to convert a IplImage type from OpenCV to ALLEGRO_BITMAP type from Allegro 5.0.x than just putting every pixel from one to another?

Like 2 for loops like this:

```
void iplImageToBitmap(IplImage *source, ALLEGRO_BITMAP* dest) {
    if(source!= NULL && dest!= NULL) {
        al_set_target_bitmap(dest);
        int height = source->height;
        int width = source->width;
        int x,y;

        for( y=0; y < height ; y++ ) {
            uchar* ptr = (uchar*) (
                source->imageData + y * source->widthStep
                );
            for( x=0; x < width; x++ ) {
                al_put_pixel(x,y,al_map_rgb(ptr[3*x+2],ptr[3*x+1],ptr[3*x]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`al_lock_bitmap`](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.4/graphics.html#al_lock_bitmap) to get an [`ALLEGRO_LOCKED_REGION`](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.4/graphics.html#allegro_locked_region), then set the pixel data as described. Then unlock it with `al_unlock_bitmap`.

Comment: Ok, it worked better, but is it the only way? its because the bitmap structure here cannot be accessed? is this fast enough? i dont know how fast OpenCV can perform such things.

Comment: @Merovigiam: Those are the tools Allegro provides. Allegro is intended for updating an image every frame. If you want to achieve maximum performance at this, then you'll need to go lower level than Allegro allows.

Comment: @Merovigiam, if you lock the bitmap in the same format as the source, then you could `memcpy` it line by line. If the lines are the same width (i.e., stride or pitch) and contiguous, you may also be able to get by with using `memcpy` on the entire thing at once.